# Laravel 5.1 setLocale is not working

Tags: laravel, localization

I was using the L5.1 localization but no matter what I do the language stays to the default config/app.php settings locale.

```
 Route::get('setlanguage/{locale}', function ($locale) {
    Session::set('locale', $locale);
    App::setLocale(session('locale')); //tried with setLocale('es') too

    return redirect()->back();
});
```

tried creating middlewares, controllers. Nothing works. I've never used this feature on my Windows Xampp server. I've always used this on Linux. Idk if permissions have anything to do with this. Idk it just doesn't change the default config of language. Also trans or Lang::get does not work on different language other than english.

Answer (score 0):

setLocale will work on runtime, meaning on the current page load only.

If you want it to change the entire application language, you need to save the user setting somewhere (session or database etc), and use that for each page load (you can probably use a middleware for that)

Comment: Nevermind i tried as you said with different method of just adding it locale in header view file. 1 line of code. Works fine.

Comment: GIVE THAT LINE OF CODE THEN PLEASE.